Calculating angle between 3 points give weird result according pattern angle
I want to calculate the angle between two segments in 2D space. The two segments are defined by AB and BC.
The result of the calculation seems to vary according to the orientation of the vectors.
function getAngle2D(A, B, C) {
        
        const A2D = { x: A.x, y: A.y };
        const B2D = { x: B.x, y: B.y };
        const C2D = { x: C.x, y: C.y };

        // Vecteurs AB et BC
        const AB = { x: B2D.x - A2D.x, y: B2D.y - A2D.y };
        const BC = { x: C2D.x - B2D.x, y: C2D.y - B2D.y };

        // Produit scalaire des vecteurs AB et BC
        const dotProduct = AB.x * BC.x + AB.y * BC.y;

        // Normes des vecteurs AB et BC
        const magnitudeAB = Math.sqrt(AB.x ** 2 + AB.y ** 2);
        const magnitudeBC = Math.sqrt(BC.x ** 2 + BC.y ** 2);

        // Calculer le cosinus de l'angle
        const cosTheta = dotProduct / (magnitudeAB * magnitudeBC);

        // Calculer l'angle en radians
        const angleRadians = Math.acos(cosTheta);

        // Convertir l'angle en degrés
        const angleDegrees = angleRadians * (180 / Math.PI);

        return angleDegrees;
    }



        // first points batch (green)
        const points1 = [
            {x: 0.5067973136901855, y: 0.5480734705924988,},
            { x: 0.5307877659797668, y: 0.5041729211807251},
            { x: 0.5793206095695496, y: 0.5759181380271912}
        ];

        // second points batch (blue)
        const points2 = [
            {  x: 0.3797118365764618, y: 0.7955537438392639,  },
            {  x: 0.3800569176673889, y: 0.7407315969467163,  },
            {x: 0.4513204097747803, y: 0.7465168237686157, }
        ];



(don't pay attention to projection lines)

I've updated my post, and my code. I tried to edit the functions to wordk with BA and BC but this dosen't solve the problem.
In fact, it's an issue in my function. According to the angle of the three points pattern, the result is different.
To get a 90° result, I need to have vectors parallel to x and y.

In my first 3d environment, yes I did.
But on this new 2D canvas, points are really at 90°. The function return is not...

Those 3 points form an angle of 90° (+/- 5) in both cases (blue and green) But for the green pattern, the function returns 117 or more depending on the orientation of the pattern...

Well, they don't. The green triangle forms angles of 62.73 ° in B, 82.35 ° in A and 34.92 ° in C. Note that in a plot, you need x and y to have the same ratio between pixels and distances to be able to correctly measure the angles.

To get the inner B angle of the triangle ABC you have indeed to start from the dot product of BA and BC; AB dot BC gives the external angle of the triangle (do a parallel translation of the vector BC from origin B to origin A). The angles as computed by @JohanC are correct (see fiddle). I don't know why you determined they should be 90 degrees.

I believe your maths is correct, and these 2 vectors are not at 90 degrees.
Were they at 90  degrees, their dot product would be zero;
Instead, the dot product of AB (-1,-1,-1) and BC (-1,1,-1) is 1.0.
Each vector has a magnitude of sqrt{3}.
Therefore cos(\theta) = 1/ sqrt{3}/ sqrt{3} = 1/3
\theta ~= 70.52 deg
Note that the angle between (-1,-1,0) and (-1,1,0) is 90 degrees. Then we add an equal Z component to both, lessening the angle.
On a side note, you're currently calculating this angle, you should check that is actually what you intend;


Thank you for your answer.
Eventually, I realize the result of the calculation seems to vary according to the orientation of the vectors. I've updated the problem with a drawing
